# Nothing was returned from render. Using C9 Workspace and unable to find issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

Hey guys I have been stuck on this for quite a while. I'm new to React and I have been trying to figure out the problem I have been having for quite a while. 
I get the error:

```
invariant.js:42 Uncaught Error: App(...): Nothing was returned from render. 
This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, 
return null.
```

I have my App.js source code here:

```
var React = require('react');
var Component = React.Component; 
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

//console.log("Hit");

class App extends Component {
//console.log("Hit");
    render(){
        return (
            <div>This is a react app.</div>
        );
}

}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

And I have my webpack.config.js here.

```
 var webpack = require("webpack");
 var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: "./src/App.js"
  },
  output: {
   filename:"build/bundle.js",
    sourceMapFilename: "build/bundle.map"
  },
  devtool: '#source-map',
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query:{
          presets:['react', 'es2015']
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

}

My index.html file here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div id= "app"></div>

        <script type= "text/javascript" src = "build/bundle.js"></script>

    </body>

</html>
```

I have looked on google and tried to find what was going on but I I tried to implement them and nothing has worked. I used webpack -w to create the bundle.js yet I can't find the problem. Is there any thing I'm doing wrong with my code. I'm not sure whether the C9 ide has anything to do with it but if there's any input that would be great.

```
{
  "name": "workspace",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
   "react": "^16.2.0",
   "react-dom": "^16.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^3.11.0"
  }
}
```

Posted here is my package.json file.

Comment: Does your call to `ReactDOM.render()` not have a first parameter?

Comment: It does have it.

Comment: It does after the edit :)

Comment: Yeah hahaha my bad.

Comment: Regardless I still encounter the problem.

Comment: have you installed `babel-preset-react`?

Comment: Yeah I did. It's version 6.24.1

Comment: hmm, I set up this exact example on c9 myself (copied your code) and got it working - can you show your `package.json` too?

Comment: Yeah I added it here. after the edit

Comment: I'm fresh out of ideas - I copied your `package.json`, deleted `node_modules` and installed again, re-ran webpack and it still works; hopefully someone can come by and help you out

Comment: Can you possibly share it with me with read only access?

Comment: Or I can share with you either or.

Comment: how do I share with you?